# Error while running two django apps on different ports of a server

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to run two django apps on different ports of a server using Apache and WSGI. Here is my VehicleDataEntry.conf (listening to port 80) file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName  104.218.50.242
    DocumentRoot /website_data/sites/VehicleDataEntry/static/
    WSGIScriptAlias / /website_data/django/VehicleDataEntry/VehicleDataEntry/wsgi.py
    Alias /static/ /website_data/sites/VehicleDataEntry/static/
</VirtualHost>

WSGIPythonPath /website_data/django/VehicleDataEntry/

<Directory "/website_data/sites/VehicleDataEntry/static">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/website_data/django/VehicleDataEntry/VehicleDataEntry">
      <Files wsgi.py>
         Require all granted
      </Files>
</Directory>
```

QuotationMaker.conf (listening on port 8080):

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName  104.218.50.242
    DocumentRoot /website_data/sites/QuotationMaker/static/
    WSGIScriptAlias / /website_data/django/QuotationMaker/QuotationMaker/wsgi.py
    Alias /static/ /website_data/sites/QuotationMaker/static/
</VirtualHost>

WSGIPythonPath /website_data/django/QuotationMaker/

<Directory "/website_data/sites/QuotationMaker/static">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/website_data/django/QuotationMaker/QuotationMaker">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Now the VehicleDataEntry's wsgi.py file:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "VehicleDataEntry.settings"
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

QuotationMaker's wsgi.py file:
VehicleDataEntry's wsgi.py file:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "QuotationMaker.settings"
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

The Problem: VehicleDataEntry app is running without any problem, however, when I try to access QuotationMaker on port 8080, it returns 500 Internal Server Error. When I checked the httpd/logs/error_log, I get the following error:

**ImportError: No module named QuotationMaker.settings**

I know there is something wrong with the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE path, have looked it up online as well, but couldn't find a solution. Please help.

Comment: your `QuotationMaker's wsgi.py` is equal `VehicleDataEntry's wsgi.py`?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was mistake while posting the question. The files are different, updated.

Comment: is your `QuotationMaker's wsgi.py` in the root dir of your QuotationMaker project?

Comment: No, it has the path /QuotationMaker/QuotationMaker/wsgi.py. Same pattern for VehicleDataEntry, like /VehicleDataEntry/VehicleDataEntry/wsgi.py.

Comment: Interestingly, when I delete VehicleDataEntry.conf, QuotationMaker app starts running on 8080 (and of course, VehicleDataEntry app is no more accessible in that case, since the conf file has been deleted).

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `WSGIPythonPath` set twice at global scope, the second will override the first.

Read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html

for other issues related to running more than one Django site.

You should use mod_wsgi daemon mode and have each Django site in its own processes.

Also read:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

which explains how to use Python virtual environments, plus further details on correct way of setting Python module search path.